# what is a numeric string

Tags: c#, facebook

I need information and can't find it. The facebook API uses and "id" field that is listed as a numeric string. The term "numeric string" is new to me and I am having trouble finding Documents explaining them. Does anyone have a resource that deals with this?

My big problem is I don't know how to convert it to a basic string for storage and comparison. I am working in Unity and c# using the Facebook Unity SDK.

Answer (score 3):

A `numeric string` is simply what the name describes. It's numbers in string format - generally used in combination with [`Standard Numeric Format Strings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx).

To convert a number (of any type) to a `string` in c# you just use the `.ToString()` method. However, if the value comes as a string this part is redundant.

```
int number = 20;
string numericString = number.ToString(); // numeric string
```

As shown above this just converts `number` to its `string` representation.

To convert it back to a format where use with (some, namely the numeric *relational* operators) [`comparative operators`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx) is possible, you can use the `.Parse()`, `.TryParse()` etc methods attached to most standard types. An example of this is as follows:

```
int number = 20;
string numericString = number.ToString();

var result = 0;
if(int.TryParse(numericString, out result)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a valid int: {0}", result);
}
else 
{
    Console.WriteLine("This string is not a valid int: {0}", numericString);
}
```

Now you can use `result` in a comparative statement with no issue.

Generally `.TryParse()` is used when you don't or won't know if the `numeric string` you're attempting to convert will, in fact, result in a numeric [`ValueType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx) being returned.  If you are sure of its success, use the `.Parse()` method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. I been working on this for several hours and was just thrown by the way they stated it. It is all working and I appreciate all the input. I don't know anyone personally that codes so this is my place for simple questions and clarification. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The term "numeric string" just means that it is a numeric value, stored inside a string variable.

Examples:

"1"

"1.0"

"-2"

These are all considered "numeric strings" because they are strings that represent numeric values.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests, numeric string is the string of **numbers** however not limited to string of 0-9.Numeric strings consist of optional sign, any number of digits, optional decimal part and optional exponential part. Thus **"+0123.45e6"** is a valid numeric string value.

> Hexadecimal (e.g. 0xf4c3b00c), Binary (e.g. 0b10100111001), Octal
>   (e.g. 0777) notation is not allowed.

Comment: I doubt an 'id' numeric string would contain anything but 0 to 9. But then it is facebook...

Comment: Exactly, answered his question just so that he doesn't get confused in the whole idea of numeric string being limited to only numbers, and how strings in hexadecimal format no longer treated as numeric. But the question lacks reasearch.